# What does these text nodes signify in DOM tree?

Tags: html, dom

For html code,

```
<p>
  <strong>C</strong>ascading
  <strong>S</strong>tyle
  <strong>S</strong>heets
</p>
```

below is the DOM tree, using DOM inspector tool,

[image]

--
What does these text nodes(highlighted in red) signify?

*Note: Beginner*

Comment: @PedroLobito Every html element(node in DOM) is a box having default `padding`/`margin`/`border`. paragraph node  `p` is also a box. So, why do we need white space?

Comment: It's the spaces between the `<p>` and the `<strong>`. They are not displayed, but they are text content.

Comment: @Pekka웃  That's interesting, `html` is not indentation based syntax.Does spaces between tags are part of html syntax?

Comment: @overexchange. Yes they are. Almost (but not quite) everywhere. Which spaces in the HTML have a effect on the rendering is due to the action of CSS, not HTML.